# Horizontal bar graph using ng2-charts in angular2

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I am new into using ng2-charts and i wanted to know is it possible to have a horizontal bar graph? I only see a vertical bar graph but i am not sure if that could be altered to include horizontal bar graph. How far can i customize a bar graph in ng2-charts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For anyone who was wondering about the same thing - i looked into the documentation for `chart.js` and was able to find just changing the bar chart type to horizontalBar works nicely. `public barChartType: string = 'horizontalBar';`

Answer (score 7):

Bar charts can be used by adjusting the "chartType" option within your baseChart canvas.

```
<canvas baseChart
        [datasets]="data"
        [labels]="label"
        chartType="horizontalBar">
```